# Get an Element in a deep stack of Html Elements

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I'm navigating to a website using `WebBrowser` object in C# and i want to get a Html Element that exist in that website but that element is in a deep ugly stack of other elements in fact the address is :

> html -> frameset -> frame#mainFrame -> html -> body -> div -> table#AutoNumber -> tbody -> tr -> td -> div -> form#lglform -> table -> tbody -> tr -> td -> table -> tbody -> tr -> td -> input#Button1

when i try to use `GetElementsByTagName("input")` i realize i have to first get to parent of that first and for that i have to get to parent of that as well and so on.
is there any way to define a single `HtmlElement` and set it to that element directly without getting through all parents?

**UPDATE**
I'm getting null as a result of GetElementById because `WebBrowser` doesn't load website correctly even though I'm using `DocumentCompleted` event to making sure of that here is what website looks like in ie inspector:

[image: website in ie]

but WebBrowser Object just load this HTML

[image: Vs]
is there any way to make `WebBrowser` Object to collect all HTML code?
or is there any another good way to approach my goal?

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois i tried GetElementById the result is null

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code ? Are you sure of the DOM structure and id / class values ?

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois i found the reason of getting null and i add some more information for you

Comment: i really don't know I'm not the website developer I'm just trying to use `webBrowser` object to fill some textfield and push a button in the page and get the result programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your input has an ID of `Button1`, use [`GetElementById`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx). Failing that though, you'd have to query `webBrowser.Document.All`, which is a collection of all the elements in the HTML document.

```
HtmlElement input = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Button1");
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried GetElementByID but the result is null. can you tell me how can i get all elements and their child from that html page?

Comment: @MasihAkbari Sure, use `webBrowser.Document.All`, that's access to all the elements.

Comment: If the Element exists it's strange you get null. I am not very familiar with webBrowser controler but maybe you are searching even if the document is not fully created. Maybe using `WebBrowser.OnDocumentCompleted` to be sure everything is loaded ?

Comment: @mattytommo problem is `WebBrowser` doesn't load the page correctly i add some more info about that

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HtmlAgilitypack and get the element by its Id `Button1`:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(/*html data here*/);
var InputButton = doc.GetElementbyId("Button1");
```

//Edit: 1 somehow ignored the fact you are using a webbrowser control, mattytommo's answer seems more easy and appropriate here.

Comment: The framework already contains `GetElementById`, you don't need HtmlAgilityPack for that :)

Comment: Yup. I complety ignored the webbrowser control.